# Initial meld and additional pair of same rank

Tags: canasta

Playing Canasta, can I make the initial meld of:
`2,A,A,A` and `8,8,8,8` = 120 and then pick up the `8` from the discard pile with `8,8` remaining in my hand?
when the situation is:

- My hand: `2,A,A,A, 8,8,8,8, 8,8, J,J,3`.
- My opponent throws an `8` to the discard pile.
- I need 120 for my initial meld.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do this, but you have the order wrong. You don’t first meld, and then pick up the discard pile. First you show the `8,8` from your hand, and lay them down along with the enough other cards so that the total meld is at least 120, which can include the value of the `8` from the discard pile as well.

From [these rules](https://www.pagat.com/rummy/canasta.html):

> in order to achieve the minimum count, you must either meld entirely from your hand after drawing from the stock, or you must use two natural cards from your hand which match the top card of the discard pile. In this second case, **you can count the value of the top discard**, along with the cards you play from your hand in this and any other melds, towards the minimum count. You cannot count any other cards in the pile which you may intend to add in the same turn.

Comment: If we play that you cannot count the value of the top discard and the pair as part of the initial meld, would you still agree that you can do this.

Comment: @Sue I don’t understand your question. It sounds like you are talking about using a house rule where you can’t use those points as part of the minimum? You can use whatever house rules you want; but it’s not how the regular game works.

Comment: @Sue looks like I misread part of your question. I have updated my answer to be more specific.